# Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am getting this error while doing install from Maven:

> Steps - Maven clean -- Running fine
>   Maven Install - "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project com.learn.selenium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process"

I am a newbie to `Selenium` , any help would be really appreciated, below is my POM xml

```
**<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.learn</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.learn.selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>demo</description>
 <properties>
<suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

</properties> 
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
<version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.40.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>

<plugins>

<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>

<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>

</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think, you need to upgrade `maven-surefire-plugin` version to `2.19.1`, if you are properly create `suiteXmlFile`. and need to specify the actual path of `suiteXmlFile`, for Example :         `<suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>`. and if you want to use `<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>`, you need to `run mvn clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile=testngSuite.xml`.
 for more you can refer bellow links(maven-surefire-plugin document):

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/maven-tutorials/how-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-testng-xml-using-maven

Comment: Hi , i figured out the same, problem was with my TestNG xml , a class was there which was not present in the original project.

Answer (score 1):

hope you will solve error with this solution..

1. **Add a latest version of "guava" dependency from mvn repository**
   [latest guava version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

   ```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

2. **and add the below pluins in to the POM.xml File**

   ```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore> false </testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>

    </plugins>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Below solution works for me !!**

Please add below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences - Java - > Installed JREs and

make sure that an entry pointing to JDK path.